# How to not use HTTPS by default when debugging a dockerized project (using Docker as host instead of IIS Express)?

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, configuration

Because of some strange cause that prevents me from installing self-generated cert (using `dotnet dev-certs`). So when debugging using Docker as host, I cannot start the app, somehow the HTTPS is always used, I've tried modifying the `launchUrl` in `launchSettings.json` from `"{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}...` to just `"http://{ServiceHost}...` but it did not work.

I've tried Googling around and found that it's caused by the environment variable named `ASPNETCORE_URLS`, I don't know how to override that value, maybe in the dockerfile …, but actually that will not be able to override the value because I can see that VS runs the `docker run` command (printed in the Output window) like this:

```
docker run … -e "ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80"
```

Yes, it puts the value there right in `docker run` command, so looks like nothing (trying to modify `ASPNETCORE_URLS` elsewhere) can override that value.

How could you change that value? I hope I can change it to exclude the `https` part. Actually the final purpose here is to not trying to use `HTTPS` when debugging. The certificate validating process will stop me from continuing.

Comment: @LexLi I understand that it's possible to use that option when running `docker run` via CLI manually. But here as I described, I use `Visual Studio` (with F5 or use Debug > Start Debugging), the `docker run` is auto-generated by Visual Studio so looks like it's out of my control (or maybe I don't know of the way to change it)

Comment: Is there any detail steps to reproduce your issue? Have you enter the http address in the web browser? After commenting out `app.UseHttpsRedirection();`, it will not redirect http request to https. You still need to access the http address manually, for default request, you need to change to `"launchUrl": "http://{ServiceHost}:54413"` with http port.

Comment: @TaoZhou it's just simple by creating an asp.net core project (with Docker support), try switching the Debugging drop-down button from IIS Express (as by default) to Docker to start debugging with Docker. Right after building OK, it pops up and asks you about creating a self-signed cert and trusting it before continuing with HTTPS. Because that step is failed for me as well so right after that it stops debugging. I think it can continue debugging OK if somehow HTTPS is not used and no CERT is required. I've tried commenting `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` out but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

you have to comment this line in `startup.cs` .

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

Comment: Sorry that I did not mention this in my question, actually I've tried this way (and rebuilt the image) but it still did not work.